Fill in the two gaps. For example, is it "various" or "varied" activities?

She brings the culture alive through __ 1 __(vary) activities like tea performances, calligraphy classes, and medicine talks, __ 2 __(promote) the Icelandic understanding of China’s rich traditions.

The above sentence is sourced from some English test of highschool in Mainland China. You should use the suitable form of the words in brackets.
My questions are:

the 1st one, various or varied, are they both correct?
the 2nd one, the -ing form 'promoting' and infinitive form 'to promote', are they both correct?


In addition to this point, I want to know if infinitive verbs act as purposeful adverbials at the end of a sentence. Does it need comma before it or is it not grammatically correct to write like this?


John often attends public lectures at the University of Cambridge, mainly to improve his English.
John often attends public lectures at the University of Cambridge, to improve his English.


My questions are also based on this URL link https://www.cpsenglish.com/question/52023, from a website focusing on English grammar teaching in China.

I'm tempted to say the question is not focused on one issue but several. Your question might get closed because it lacks focus. In your shoes I would ask a new question for part two, i.e the one about punctuation

various versus varied

"promiting" means the activities cause understanding, while "to promote" means that this was her purpose in performing those activities (it's short for "in order to promote").

The first blank on the test isn't terribly clear. It would be very nice if it accepted several valid answers. You didn't post the instructions, but I'm guessing it's something like "Choose the correct form of the verb to fill in the blank." The problem is that this blank is acting like an adjective, modifying "activities."
"Various" is an adjective closely related to the verb "vary," but it's not "a form of 'vary.'" "Varied" is closer, but it would be understood as a participle, not as the past tense of "vary." Another similar example is "varying": it could be mistaken for the -ing form of "vary," but is still an adjective here.
Outside of the test, if asking which to use, all are fine; "various" might be the simplest and most natural.
For the second blank, you're right that "promoting" and "to promote" would both fit here. And this time "promoting" would be a real -ing verb, not an adjective. But "to promote," in this context, would not be an infinitive. The "to" would be understood as "in order to." That might make "promoting" the best choice for the test, though I doubt you're supposed to think that narrowly about it.
